# Change background-color for td

Tags: jquery, colors, background, html-table

if `background color` of td `== color1` then change `td background-color` to *color2*.

```
<table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" class="table table-condensed">
<tbody><tr><td style="background-color:#00FF60">1</td></tr></tbody></table>
```

My jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if($('td').css('background-color') == 'rgb(0, 255, 96)') {
       $('td').css('background-color','red');
    }
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/voxtermen/c9yz5c5L/4/

Comment: You have not added jquery library.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you have to include jQuery. Then loop for each `td` element and set `background-color` based on preferences

Try:

```
$("td").each(function (index) {

        if ($(this).css('background-color') == 'rgb(0, 255, 96)') {
            $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
        }
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/c9yz5c5L/11/)

Answer (score 1):

You have not added jQuery library to the jsfiddle ( add it from dropdown on the left side).
Also you need to iterate `td`s using `.each()` and then check `background-color` for `td` , see below code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('td').each(function(){

        if($(this).css('background-color') == 'rgb(0, 255, 96)') {
           $(this).css('background-color','red');
        }
    });
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/c9yz5c5L/9/)**

Answer (score 1):

**Frist, include jquery library; second, remove "$(document).ready(function(){" since you selected "onLoad". replace the following code to your JavaScript part**

```
$('td').each(function(){
    if($(this).css('background-color') === 'rgb(0, 255, 96)') {
       $(this).css('background-color','red');
    }
});
```